# Display Product Count in WooCommerce category with subcategory

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, count, categories, product

How to display total number of product in category with subcategory in WooCommerce?
I'm try using this code, but it work perfectly only in categories without subcategory.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_product_count_view', 10);

  function add_product_count_view() {
    global $wp_query;

    $category_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $term = get_term( $category_id, 'product_cat' );  

    echo $term->name . '(' . $term->count . ')';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in function.php:

```
  add_action( 'count_product_title', 'add_product_count_view', 10);

  function add_product_count_view() {
    global $wp_query;

    $category_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
    //echo sprintf( _n( '%d товар', '%d товаров', $term->count ), $term->count );
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category_id, 
            'include_children' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'nopaging' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    ) );

    if( function_exists("is_shop") && $category_id != 0) {
    echo '(' .esc_html( $query->post_count ) . ')';
    }
  }
```

Paste in your template 
`<?php do_action('count_product_title');?>`